# Two select statements querying the same column in a view returning different data

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a view that I will call 'ProductsView'. The column in this view that I have queried is called 'ProductName'.

```
Select ProductName 
from ProductsView
where ProductID = '12345678'

Result: 'Book'
```

Then I create a new query that inner joins two views (one of which is the aforementioned 'ProductsView'). Here we have another two views called 'TransactionsView' and 'ProductionView'.

```
Select
TV.Column
TV.Column
PRV.Column
PRV.Column
PV.ProductName
From TransactionView as TV
Inner Join ProductsView as PV
On TV.ID = PV.ID
Inner Join ProductionView as PRV
on TV.ID = PRV.ID
where PV.ProductID = '12345678'

Result (for ProductName column): '325 Pages'
```

As seen above I have included the ProductName column is included in this query as well so you would assume that one of the rows returned would have the value of 'Book' inside the ProductName column, however it doesn't even return the same type of data.

I'm at a complete loss of why this is happening. Could this be something to do with the underlying tables?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see commas in your code, could be that you take `ProductName` as an alias for `PRV.Column`

Comment: Can you show the definition of the ProductView? If I had to guess, I'd say you have `TOP 1` without an order by or some other non-deterministic logic within the view that means different execution plans will mean different records are returned.

Comment: @Dordi I think it's just really bad copy/paste or transcribe. What's in the question is not _exactly_ what the OP is running, but you can't alias like that. Maybe if it is `PRV.Column [PV.ProductName]`... but hopefully the OP can correct the query because the question cannot possibly show the actual query.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing some sample data and both the results you get now and the expected results it's impossible to tell, we can't see your data....

Having said that, some basic trouble shooting might go like this.

First make sure that the columns you are joining are of the same datatype, you ProductID appears to be text (based on the fact that you quoted the value you are querying against).

Then, start with your ProductsView query

```
SELECT * 
    FROM ProductsView PV
    WHERE PV.ProductID = '12345678'
```

Make sure that returns what you expect

Then Join the TransactionView

```
SELECT * 
    FROM ProductsView PV
        JOIN TransactionView TV ON PV.ID = TV.ID
    WHERE PV.ProductID = '12345678'
```

Again, check if you get the expected results and if so, finally join the ProductionView

```
SELECT * 
    FROM ProductsView PV
        JOIN TransactionView TV ON PV.ID = TV.ID
        JOIN ProductionView PRV ON PRV.ID = TV.ID
    WHERE PV.ProductID = '12345678'
```

Once you see where the results change it will narrow down the issue. Having said all that as you are not left joining then its' hard to see how you can get differing values between your two queries as the column you are questioning comes from the same table as the filter in the WHERE clause. I would expect to seethe same value or  no records (if one or more joins failed)